# type TypeViewOne does not conform to protocol UITableViewDataSource

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This is my code

```
class TableViewOne: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("firstCell") as! firstCell
        let index = indexPath.row
        cell.labelMy.text = ViewController.firstData![index]
        return cell

    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let s = ViewController.firstData {
            return s.count
        }
        return 0
    }

}
```

I don't know why this time I am getting this error though when I use a subclass of `UITableViewController` those would be enough, sounds like the `UITableViewControlelr` has implemented for other required functions, but I couldn't know them my self.

Comment: This seems like "old-swift" syntax. What is your `TableViewOne` class, can it not be a `UITableViewController`? If so, replace class header with `class TableViewOne: UITableViewController { ...`.

Comment: Taking a stab in the dark here, but will it work if TableViewOne extends UIView? e.g. `class TableViewOne: UIView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UITableViewDataSource` requires you to conform to the `NSObject` protocol which `TableViewOne`, a pure swift class, does not. Change your declaration to inherit from `NSObject` like this:

```
class TableViewOne: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
```

Second, you don't need the `override` keyword because `TableViewOne` is not subclassing another object. `UITableViewController` has a default implementation of returning 1, but because you aren't subclassing `UITableViewController` you have no method to override.

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
```

vs.

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you draged `datasource` and `delegate` from `storyboard` or `xib` to your class. Same like this:

[image]

`Datasource` will make your class conform to: `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, `numberOfSection`, `numberRowInSection`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have taken a UIViewController in storyboard & added a UITableView to it, if thats the case then subclass UIViewController & change your class like this

```
class TableViewOne: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
```

If you have taken TableViewController in storyboard then you need to subclass only UITableViewController

```
class TableViewOne: UITableViewController{
```

& you only need to add following functions to confirm to tableview data source

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 0
}
```